# Injected mocked dependency into ViewModel while unit testing not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, viewmodel

I'm trying to do unit testing in view model by using Moq and dependency injection

Basically, I have model: Class `PersonModel` containing properties `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Input`, `Output` - no logic or any methods in here.

In my `ViewModel`, I have:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private IGetService getService;
    private Personmodel personModel;
    private string result;

    public ViewModel(IGetService getService)
    {
        personModel= new Personmodel ();
        this.getService = getService;
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return personModel.FirstName + " " + personModel.LastName; }
    }
    public string Result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set { result = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return personModel.FirstName; }
        set { personModel.FirstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return personModel.LastName; }
        set { personModel.LastName = value; }
    }

    public string Input
    {
        get { return personModel.Input; }
        set { personModel.Input= value; }
    }

    public string Output
    {
        get { return personModel.Output; }
        set { personModel.Output= value; }
    }

    public string Result
    {
        get { return result; }
        set { result = value; }
    }        
    public void ResultFromModelToView()
    {
        getService.GetOutput(personModel);
        Result = string.Join(",", FullName,personModel.Output);            
    }
}
```

For `IGetService`,

```
public interface IGetService
{
    void GetOutput(PersonModel personModel);
}
```

The implementation of `GetService` is pretty much getting `personModel.Outout` value depending on business logic

Here is my `ViewModelTests`

```
public class ViewModelTests
{

    private Mock<IGetService> GetServiceMock{ get; set; }
    private ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        GetServiceMock= new Mock<IGetService>();
        ViewModel = new ViewModel (GetServiceMock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetResultTests()
    {
        // Arrange
        GetServiceMock.Setup(x =>  x.GetOutput(It.Is<PersonModel>(
            p=> p.FirstName == "FirstName" &&
                    p.LastName == "LastName" &&
                    p.Input == "Input"
            )));

        // Act
        ViewModel.ResultFromModelToView();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(ViewModel.Result, "FirstName,LastName,Output");

    }
}
```

When I run the test I'm getting

> Assert failed, with expected result of ",,"

What have I missed?

Comment: Where are you setting/populating the values on the ViewModel?

Comment: The whole thing is pretty confusing I have to say. `IGetService` has a method called `GetOutput` that doesn't return anything. In `ViewModel` you need to know that before you can use `Result` you have to call `ResultFromModelToView()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the design of the view model, you were not assigning values to the model that would allow the test to be exercised to completion based on how the mock was set up. You would also need to have the mock mimic the expected behavior of setting the output on the model when `GetOutput` was invoked.

The expectation in the assertion is also wrong because `ViewModel.FullName` is defined as

```
public string FullName {
    get { return personModel.FirstName + " " + personModel.LastName; }
}
```

Note the space between the names and not the comma of the expected result `"FirstName,LastName,Output"`. Which would cause the test to fail even if you provided the necessary values to the view model.

Review the following changes made to the test based on the original example provided

```
[TestClass]
public class ViewModelTests {

    private Mock<IGetService> GetServiceMock{ get; set; }
    private ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        GetServiceMock= new Mock<IGetService>();
        ViewModel = new ViewModel (GetServiceMock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetResultTests() {
        // Arrange
        var expectedFirstName = "FirstName";
        var expectedLastName = "LastName";
        var expectedInput = "Input";
        var expectedOutput = "Output";
        var expectedResult = "FirstName LastName,Output";

        //set properties on view model
        ViewModel.FirstName = expectedFirstName;
        ViewModel.LastName = expectedLastName;
        ViewModel.Input = expectedInput;

        //Arrange mock to expect specific model
        GetServiceMock
            .Setup(_ => _.GetOutput(It.Is<PersonModel>(p=> 
                p.FirstName == expectedFirstName &&
                p.LastName == expectedLastName &&
                p.Input == expectedInput
            )))
            .Callback((PersonModel p) => { // <-- use callback to set Output on model
                p.Output = expectedOutput;
            });

        // Act
        ViewModel.ResultFromModelToView();
        actualResult = ViewModel.Result;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help @nkosi. that works!
I'm not quite clear on
"Given the View model, you were not assigning values to the model that would allow the test to be exercised to completion " 
How should I assign values to model? or my design of MVVM is somewhat not right there?
For view, i'm using windows forms, which should notified changes on First name, last name, etc.

Comment: @user9572542 no where in your test were you assigning values to the view model. And given that the view model was just exposing values passed to the model, then the test would not have work because there were no values to compare.